# Express js optional parameter

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking to add an optional parameter to an express route where var1 has to be set but var 2 can be ommited (/test/0 and /test/0/0 should both work).

I could create another rule, or juste evaluate the string "test/0/0" but I'm wondering if there is no other way.

```
app.get('/test/:var1/:var2', function(req, res){
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
app.get('/test/:var1/:var2*?',function(req,res)
   {
if(!req.params.var2){
// do something when there is no optionalParam
  }
res.json({ var: req.params.var1,
          var2: req.params.var2 });

});
```

just call

http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/44

**output**

> {"var":"44"}

incase of passing both

> {"var":"44","var2":"77"}

Comment: What does `*` do ?